# BlackBerry app auto-update

Tags: java, blackberry

Is there any API for checking if there are any updates for an installed application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to build this yourself if you distribute your application through AppWorld. When you publish a new version in AppWorld, it will do the work of informing the users that an update is available.